How to make machine always turn on after a power outage
I have a Windows 10 machine (Lenovo ThinkCentre M910q) in my home that hosts a html server that should be always on, 24x7. This machine is connected to a nobreak but sometimes a power outage in my area can last for some hours and even the nobreak ends up without power, and the machine turns off.
In these situations, I'm trying to find a way to make the machine power on automatically after the energy comes back.
How can this be achieved ?

@grawity TBF, I use much worse machines as 24/7 servers and the SFF machine as personal server thing is quite youtube/internet popular and often done.

Have you looked in the firmware settings? It’s a relatively standard feature in firmware for most systems that are designed to be used in a fixed location to have an option to control what to do after unexpected power loss (usually choosing between staying off (the typical default), turning on unconditionally, and turning on only if the system was on before the power loss).

Using the Lenovo BIOS Simulator selected ThinkCentre M910q as the device.
Got to the interactive web interface on ThinkCentre M910q (10MU,10MV,10MW,10MX,10QN). Clicked on the Power page and there is the After Power Loss option which has the help message:

This field controls whether the system will stay on after AC power is removed and then restored.

Select "Power On" if you use a power strip to turn the system on.
Select "Power Off" if you want the system to remain off after power restored.
Select "Last State" to have the system return to the previous state.


Therefore, you should be able to enter the BIOS and on the Power page set the After Power Loss option to [Power On] to cause the ThinkCentre M910q to automatically power on when AC power is restored after a loss.
This is what it looks like on the BIOS simulator:



While I don't have a ThinkCentre M910q to test this will work, since Lenovo have made a BIOS Simulator available on line expect it to work.

If you have multiple computers you want to turn back on automatically, check if the firmware has a setting for a power-on delay, and set it to Random or set every computer to a different value. This will avoid the inrush current from several computers turning on at the same time tripping a breaker. Ask me how I know :-D
